# Excel VBA Print adds new line

Tags: excel, vba, printing

Months ago I wrote a small Makro for my Company and until now it worked just fine.
Recently (maybe because we updated Office Version) there is a bug, that excel adds a new line in a print statement.

Code:

```
outputString = value1 & "                  " & value2 & "                  " & value3 & "                  " & value4 & "               " & value5 & "                 " & user & "                  " & date
```

used to give me this output:

```
22 S ***/***s                     9932256                     B*****t                                         Fatma                                        811                 R******r Alexander                 27.12.2019
```

now gives me this output:

```
22 S ***/***s                     9932256                     B*****t                                         Fatma                                        811                 R******r Alexander                 
                   27.12.2019
```

As you can see, excel adds a  newline.

Can somebody tell me what happends here?

EDIT:

Solution:

Excel adds the new line after using:

> user = Application.UserName

Maybe this is due to the office update we had. So I just took substring and cut the last character and works fine now.

Comment: What is the len of  `outputString`? And how do you define new line? Are there any `vbCrLf` or `vbLf` in `outputString`? The output you showed ist from which output device? Please also show the statement you use to print `outputString`.

Comment: No I don't use any of that. The lenght of the string is also not the problem. Naturally these were the first things I checked. Excel adds a new line after Application.UserName, do you know how i can remove the new line??

Comment: Then again the question: How do you define new line? `Application.Username` returns a string without a `vbCrLf` or `vbLf` at the end. So, I do not think a `Replace(user,vbLf,"")`  or `Replace(user,vbCrLf,"")` will help you but you can give it a try. To be honest I find it a bit offensive just to disregard my questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was kinda pissed since this is a stupid problem in my opinion. I found the solution: (Maybe because of Office update) The Application.UserName function now adds a new line at the end. So i took substring and cut the new line. Works fine now. Thank you very much for you help and sorry again <3

Comment: If you found the solution it'd be great to share the fix so others can avoid such errors. I do not think that `Application.UserName` adds a new line, i.e. vbCrlf or vbLf. What is a new line for you?

Comment: I wanted you to be the first to see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Application.Username](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.username) returns as the documentation states the username. As it is `Read/write` it can indeed happen that you will get a username that contains a `vbLf` or `vbCrLf`. Have a look at the following example

```
Sub UserName_VbCrlf()
    Dim origUser As String
    Dim user As String

    ' Be careful when testing as it replaces your username!!
    ' Maybe you save it first
    origUser = Application.UserName

    Application.UserName = "Storax" & vbLf & "Home adress"
    user = Application.UserName

    ' This will give different lengths
    Debug.Print Len(user), Len(Replace(user, vbLf, ""))

    ' Restore original username
    Application.UserName = origUser

End Sub
```